# AddHangfireServer with additional processes

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I am getting started with Hangfire and building it to run the background jobs in a console app instead of aspnet.  I see that the sqlstorage has background processes and want to add an additional one. There is an argument on `AddHangfireServer` to include additional processes, however, it requires the JobStorage. While ConfiguringServices `JobStorage.Current` throws an exception `Current JobStorage instance has not been initialized yet`. I did find that I can create a descendant of the SqlStorage and add an item to `GetComponents` but it is marked Obsolete. How can I set this using the non-obsolete method?

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, cb) => ConfigBuilder(cb, args))
                .ConfigureServices((ctx, svcColl) => ConfigureServices(svcColl, ctx.Configuration))
                .ConfigureLogging(Configurelogging)
                .Build()
                .Run();
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration cfg) {
    var dbcs = cfg.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:DB");
    _ = services.AddHangfire(gc => {
        _ = gc
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(dbcs);
    });

    _ = services.AddHangfireServer(JobStorage.Current, new[] { new MyProcess { } });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Current JobStorage instance has not been initialized yet

As answered here [jobstorage not initialized](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/jobstorage-current-property-value-has-not-been-initialized/884)

> You should call JobStorage.Current = new
> SqlServerStorage("ConnectionStringName", options) before initializing
> your BackgroundJobServer.

Now regarding this

> I see that the sqlstorage has background processes and want to add an
> additional one

**Option 1**

```
 JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connectionString");
 _ = services.AddHangfireServer(storage: JobStorage.Current , additionalProcesses: new[] { new MyProcess()} );
```

**Option 2**

> Any class registered in the DI as IBackgroundProcess is automatically
> added as an additional service

[IBackgroundProcess](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/3c42f0b8d5ec5ded223cde6e5f378966ba4db758/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L221).
From the source code, You simply have your class implement this interface and register it in the DI Container, it will interrogate your DI container via `services.GetServices` to get any registrations you've made.

```
  services.AddTransient<IBackgroundProcess, BackgroundWorker>();
```

and then in here there will be no need to add it under additional processes

```
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connectionString");

_ = builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(storage: JobStorage.Current);
```